# Getting py2exe to work with zope.interface

Tags: python, pygtk, twisted, py2exe, zope.interface

I have a Python app based on Twisted and PyGTK. Twisted itself depends on zope.interface, and I don't import it directly.

Unfortunately, when I try to run my app, the following error ends up in the error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tasks.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "ui\__init__.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "twisted\python\log.pyc", line 17, in <module>
ImportError: No module named zope.interface
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tasks.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "ui\__init__.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "twisted\python\log.pyc", line 17, in <module>
ImportError: No module named zope.interface
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tasks.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "ui\__init__.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "twisted\python\log.pyc", line 17, in <module>
ImportError: No module named zope.interface
```

I've tried adding every combination of `zope.interface` and `zope` to `INCLUDES` and `PACKAGES`, but doing so only gives me this **build time** error:

```
running py2exe
*** searching for required modules ***
C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py:16: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
  import sets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 75, in <module>
    'gtk/*.ui'
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 296, in _run
    self.find_needed_modules(mf, required_files, required_modules)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1306, in find_needed_modules
    mf.import_hook(f)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 204, in find_head_package
    raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname
ImportError: No module named zope
```

My `setup.py` is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

def find_data_files(source,target,patterns):
    # I've elided this, I doubt it's relevant to the problem
    # ...

INCLUDES = [
    'cairo',
    'pango',
    'pangocairo',
    'atk',
    'gobject',
    'gio',
]

PACKAGES = [
    'encodings',
]

setup(
    name = 'MyApp',
    description = 'My Application',
    version = '1.0',

    windows = [
                  {
                      'script': os.path.join('ui','tasks.py'),
                      'icon_resources': [
                            (1, os.path.join(
                                'ui','data','iconpack.ico'))
                        ],
                  }
              ],

    options = {
                  'py2exe': {
                      'packages': ','.join(PACKAGES),
                      'includes': ','.join(INCLUDES),
                  }
              },

    data_files = find_data_files(
                    'ui', 'ui', [
                        'data/*',
                        'gtk/*.ui'
                    ])

)
```

How do I get py2exe to build this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had this same problem with `zope.interface` and friends (zope.component, et al). Specifically it is a problem with how `py2exe` searches and discovers packages **AND** how the `zope` packages are installed.

`zope` is a namespace package and as a result relies on some funky import logic in it's `.pth` files (see `zope.interface-3.*.*-py2.*-nspkg.pth`) in order to add it's sub-packages to python's path. Have a look at it in `site-packages` and you'll see what I mean.

`py2exe` has problems "discovering" this kind of package.

In the end what I did was manually repackage the various `zope` packages I was using into a stardard module setup in `site-packages` and then reran `py2exe` - which then discovered everything no problem. It's a PITA, but until `py2exe` is able to handle packaging edge cases and/or the `zope` packages are packaged in a `py2exe` friendly fashion, it's about the best you can do.

Comment: I went to check that I could do this without running afoul of their license. Is it just me, or is the Zope Public License not actually included with any of their distributions?

Comment: There is a reference to the license include at the top of the actual code files - which is all they need. You are not doing anything contrary to the license (i.e. you are not actually changing the code in any way), you're just altering how the package is installed on your system. It's not any different than what py2exe already does with all your python libraries it packs into an exe.

Comment: Bah, [here it is](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ztk-steering-group/zope.interface/trunk/view/head:/LICENSE.txt).

Comment: my impression is that it'd still be creating a derived work, but it looks like the license is fairly liberal about that anyway, so no matter.

Comment: Okay, I'm marking this as the answer, since it got me past this phase, but now py2exe is choking on pretty much every other package I use so I'm abandoning it. So for anyone else reading this, I have no way to verify whether it worked in the final built executable :/

Comment: ah, yeah, py2exe takes a bit of work sometimes to get all the various packages to bundle. Usually py2exe is pretty good at letting you know which libraries it has trouble with, but some (like zope) take some investigation. There are a number of tips, etc. on the py2exe website, but its a bit disorganized and takes a bit of digging. I've packaged an app with wxPython, zope, and a few others and it took me several painful days to sort through the problem. Once it was done, everything worked nicely. Getting there is just a PITA.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I just need to stick with it. I get the feeling it's not going to be easier with any other system.

Comment: Having to repackage can be avoided by using Spencer's really simple answer below.

Answer (score 24):

I don't know if you ever solved this, or if it's even relevant to you anymore, but for future searchers, I found an easy way to fix the zope import problem [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2010-December/023243.html).

Specifically, add an empty `__init__.py` file to the `PYTHONDIR/Lib/site-packages/zope` directory.

I tested this with a `twisted` application, using this setup file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
File: setup.py
Author: Spencer Rathbun
Date: 07/24/2012
Description: Setup file for py2exe, converts client python script into executable.
'''
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

INCLUDES = [
    ''
]

PACKAGES = [
    'twisted'
]

setup(
        name = 'client',
        description = '',
        version = '1.0',

        console = [
            {"script":"client.py",
                "icon_resources":[
                    (1, "c:\python27\DLLs\py.ico")
                    ]
                }
            ],
        zipfile = None,

        options = {"py2exe":
            {"compressed": 1,
                "optimize": 1,
                "ascii": 0,
                "bundle_files": 1,

                "packages": ','.join(PACKAGES),
                "includes": ','.join(INCLUDES),
                }
            }
        )
```

Py2exe can use this to successfully create an executable for twisted now, since it depends upon zope.

Comment: This worked for me, should be the accepted answer imo

Comment: Yep, this is by far the best answer. thanks for that

Comment: Yes, worked for me with the repoze (repoze.lru) module required by the routes module.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this issue in creating a package using py2exe in Windows XP SP3. I figured out that py2exe was not determining the dependencies correctly.

To solve this issue, I uninstalled my third party package(s) and installed them using following easy_install command

`easy_install -Z <your_package_name>`

The -Z option unzips the package details, and hence the content is not compressed. When you run py2exe now, it will correctly detect the dependencies.

Hope this helps!