# ImportError: No module named mpl_toolkits with maptlotlib 1.3.0 and py2exe

Tags: python, matplotlib, py2exe, python-import

I can't figure out how to be able to package this via py2exe now:

I am running the command:

```
python setup2.py py2exe
```

via python 2.7.5 and matplotlib 1.3.0 and py2exe 0.6.9 and 0.6.10dev

This worked with matplotlib 1.2.x

I have read http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs and tried to implement the suggestions for handling the mpl_toolkits since it's having become a namespace package.

I'm trying to get an answer here too: http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/1-3-0-and-py2exe-regression-td41723.html

Adding an empty `__init__.py` to mpl_toolkits makes it work, but this is only a workaround to the problem.

**Can anyone suggest what I need to make py2exe work with mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 in matplotlib 1.3.0 ?:**

---

test_mpl.py is:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable, axes_size

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print make_axes_locatable, axes_size
```

---

setup2.py is:

```
import py2exe
import distutils.sysconfig
from distutils.core import setup

# attempts to get it to work
import modulefinder
import matplotlib
import mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace("mpl_toolkits")
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace("mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1")
modulefinder.AddPackagePath("mpl_toolkits", matplotlib.__path__[0])
modulefinder.AddPackagePath("mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1", mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.__path__[0])

# end of attempts to get it to work

options={'py2exe': {'packages' : ['matplotlib', 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1', 'pylab', 'zmq'],
                    'includes': ['zmq', 'six'],
                    'excludes': ['_gdk', '_gtk', '_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'PyQt4.uic.port_v3', 'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter', 'tcl'],
                    'dll_excludes': ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
                                     'libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll',
                                     'libgobject-2.0-0.dll',
                                     'tcl85.dll',
                                     'tk85.dll'],
                    'skip_archive': True },}

setup(console=['test_mpl.py'], options=options)
```

---

output is:

```
running py2exe
*** searching for required modules ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup2.py", line 23, in <module>
    setup(console=['test_mpl.py'], options=options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 296, in _run
    self.find_needed_modules(mf, required_files, required_modules)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1308, in find_needed_modules
    mf.import_hook(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 204, in find_head_package
    raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname
ImportError: No module named mpl_toolkits
```

Comment: you should really use pyinstaller, its the best out there

Comment: We intend to move to cx_freeze given that unlike pyinstaller, it is py3k compatible, but py2exe is the incumbent in this space

Comment: pyinstaller has the same error, cx_Freeze unfortunately has problems with some tricks in numpy 1.7.x.

Comment: I struggle with a similar "No module named mpl_toolkits.axes_grid" while trying to import astro-delight package. No solution seems to be around. Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 26):

There is a quite simple workaround to this problem. Find the directory from which mpl_tools is imported and simply add an empty text file named `__init__.py` in that directory. py2exe will now find and include this module without any special imports needed in the setup file.

You can find the mpl_tools directory by typing the following in a python console:

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module('mpl_toolkits').__path__
```

I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11632115/2166823 and it seems to apply to namespace packages in general.

Comment: i'd already added that in my original question: "Adding an empty __init__.py to mpl_toolkits makes it work, but this is only a workaround to the problem."

Comment: My bad, I read your question over at the matplotlib emailing list forum and then posted the workaround on there and here. Didn't notice that you added that line here.

Comment: Now the real question is why the `__init__.py` is left out in the first place. All I've got so far is "something something namespace packages".

Answer (score 11):

This problem happened to me after I update MacOS to Sierra from El Capitan.

```
sudo pip install -U matplotlib
```

solved my problem.

This page https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl/issues/294  might help you as well.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had this error " no module named 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid' " and it was because of this line " from mpl_toolkits.**axes_grid**.inset_locator import inset_axes "

I realised that in previous versions the toolkit had a single namespace of "axes_grid". In more recent version (since svn r8226), the toolkit has divided into two separate namespace ("axes_grid1" and "axisartist").

So I changed to " from mpl_toolkits.**axes_grid1**.inset_locator import inset_axes " and problem solved!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Most folders in the site-packages directory in a Python installation are packages (they have an __init__.py file). If there is no __init__.py file, then the package is called a *namespace package*. cx_Freeze has an option to indicate that mpl_toolkits is a namespace package, so the subpackages can be found.

Comment: thanks, that had been my preferred route, but as i'd mentioned in my comments, cx_Freeze had problems with numpy instead.

Comment: Ah, I forgot you wrote that. I came back to this question after a few days and didn't read it in detail again. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is an module for it now

```
conda install basemap
```

Answer (score 0):

**Because maybe you forgot to install matplotlib. Please install first then import will work fine hopefully.**

**for Python just write this:**

```
pip install matplotlib
```

**for Python 3 write this:**

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

**for Anaconda write this:**

```
conda install matplotlib
```